# Javascript Regex to Limit number of characters per line

Tags: javascript, regex, character, line, limit

I'm trying to create a JS Regular Expression to limit the amount of characters per line in an html text area. Ideally I would prefer to have it as a Javascript Regex as it's easier to use for our form validation engine.

I would like to create a regular expression that validates that a string has 10 characters per line, and a max of 3 lines

The idea would be to validate strings like the following ones:

```
01234567890
a
b
```

First line here has 11 characters so the whole string should be rejected/

```
a
b
c
d
```

This text has 4 lines so it should also be rejected.

I've tried with the following regex but is not working as expected:

`^((?:\n)?[^\n]{0,10}){0,3}$`

any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^.{0,10}(?:\r?\n.{0,10}){0,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOI5to/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.{0,10}` - zero to ten chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\r?\n.{0,10}){0,2}` - zero, one or two occurrences of

  - `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF line ending
  - `.{0,10}` - zero to ten chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

JavaScript:

```js
const valid_rx = /^.{0,10}(?:\r?\n.{0,10}){0,2}$/;
const testFunc = () => {
    if(!valid_rx.test(document.all.mytextarea.value))
    {
        console.log("Please use correct format.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea" cols="50" rows="10">a
b
c
</textarea>
<button onclick="testFunc()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: The edit queue is full so cannot do this at the moment, but please note that ^^ and $ is not start/end of string, but rather start/end of line.
Important difference for validating user input. \A and \z is start/end of string.

Comment: @MahNas92 You are mistaken. This is a JavaScript thread. Mind the ECMAScript flavor.

Comment: Ah, completely missed that, came here from a search engine and was fully focused on the regex itself. My bad, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @MahNas92 What you said is related to Ruby (Onigmo/Oniguruma) regex flavor, where `^` and `$` match line start/end and `\A`/`\z` match start/end of string.

Comment: this is also true for Java regex flavor, and for Kotlin (which I think uses Java too). But it seems to be standard (or at least main-stream) too. I cannot find any reference pinning it to a specific flavor. Maybe you can help me with such a source/reference?

Comment: @MahNas92 There is no such reference, you must be confusing the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors when used with the `/m` flag in JavaScript. Without the `/m` flag, `^` only matches the very start of string and `$` matches *the very end* of string - again, in [ECMAScript regex flavor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-compileassertion).